# frequency of objects in an array using Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

If i had a list of balls each of which has a color property. how can i cleanly get the list of balls with the most frequent color.

```
[m1,m2,m3,m4]
```

say,

```
        m1.color = blue
        m2.color = blue
        m3.color = red
        m4.color = blue
```

`[m1,m2,m4]` is the list of balls with the most frequent color

My Approach is to do:

```
[m1,m2,m3,m4].group_by{|ball| ball.color}.each do |samecolor|
  my_items = samecolor.count
end
```

where count is defined as

```
class Array
  def count
  k =Hash.new(0)
  self.each{|x|k[x]+=1}
  k
  end
end
```

my_items will be a hash of frequencies foreach same color group. My implementation could be buggy and i feel there must be a better and more smarter way. 
any ideas please?

Comment: if you are getting data from a db try to optimize the sql for faster computations

Comment: Unless your data sets are very small, I highly recommend using a linear time solution like mine below. If you're iterating more than once over the same data (e.g. group_by followed by each or each followed by sort) you're doing up to twice as much work as you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't bad, but it is inefficient. If I were you I would seek a solution that iterates through your array only once, like this:

```
balls = [m1, m2, m3, m4]
most_idx = nil

groups = balls.inject({}) do |hsh, ball|
  hsh[ball.color] = [] if hsh[ball.color].nil?
  hsh[ball.color] << ball

  most_idx = ball.color if hsh[most_idx].nil? || hsh[ball.color].size > hsh[most_idx].size 
  hsh
end

groups[most_idx] # => [m1,m2,m4]
```

This does basically the same thing as `group_by`, but at the same time it counts up the groups and keeps a record of which group is largest (`most_idx`).

Comment: Hmm, I'd want to benchmark it. Calling the core (implemented in C) methods certainly gives you great gains in performance.

Comment: Inject is an extremely short method if you look at the source--it's just an assignment followed by an each and a return. If you want to use each directly instead you can, but you won't see any performance gains. Either way, iterating only once is what's important.

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.src/M003140.html

Comment: Your assumption that "iterating once is what's important" is quite wrong when it comes to Ruby. I tested both your algorithms in Ruby 1.8.7 with arrays of randomly generated balls increasing in size up to 1 million and yours was vastly slower than eastafri in every bracket. In general, combining the built-in functions in Ruby will be faster than rolling your own "optimized version."

Comment: Just to clarify (since it's too late to edit): I'm not saying I think this is a bad solution. Just that you'll want to test with your particular Ruby implementation on your particular dataset to make sure that the algorithm's complexity isn't outweighed by other factors.

Comment: Fair enough. I appreciate your rigor.

Comment: Thanks Everyone for the discussion and the advice!

Answer (score 5):

You found `group_by` but missed `max_by`

```
max_color, max_balls = [m1,m2,m3,m4].group_by {|b| b.color}.max_by {|color, balls| balls.length}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

`color,balls = [m1,m2,m3,m4].group_by { |b| b.color }.max_by(&:size)`

Comment: or even `[a,b,c,d].group_by{|z| z.color}.values.max_by(&:size)`

Comment: Note: This assumes Ruby 1.9.1

Comment: and the question already uses `group_by`, so we can assume at least 1.8.7 is OK

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it. The basic idea uses inject to accumulate the values into a hash, and comes from "12 - Building a Histogram" in "The Ruby Cookbook".

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class M
  attr_reader :color
  def initialize(c)
    @color = c
  end
end

m1 = M.new('blue')
m2 = M.new('blue')
m3 = M.new('red')
m4 = M.new('blue')

hash = [m1.color, m2.color, m3.color, m4.color].inject(Hash.new(0)){ |h, x| h[x] += 1; h } # => {"blue"=>3, "red"=>1}
hash = [m1, m2, m3, m4].inject(Hash.new(0)){ |h, x| h[x.color] += 1; h } # => {"blue"=>3, "red"=>1}
```

There are two different ways to do it, depending on how much knowledge you want the inject() to know about your objects.

Answer (score 2):

this produces a reverse sorted list of balls by frequency

```
balls.group_by { |b| b.color }
  .map { |k, v| [k, v.size] }
  .sort_by { |k, count| -count}
```

Answer (score 2):

two parts, I'll use your strange balls example but will also include my own rails example

```
ary = [m1,m2,m3,m4]
colors = ary.each.map(&:color) #or ary.each.map {|t| t.color }
Hash[colors.group_by(&:w).map {|w, ws| [w, ws.length] }]
#=> {"blue" => 3, "red" => 1 }
```

my ActiveRecord example

```
stocks = Sp500Stock.all
Hash[stocks.group_by(&:sector).map {|w, s| [w, s.length] }].sort_by { |k,v| v }
#=> {"Health Care" => 36, etc]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myhash = {}

mylist.each do |ball|
  if myhash[ball.color]
    myhash[ball.color] += 1
  else
    myhash[ball.color] = 1    
  end
end

puts myhash.sort{|a,b| b[1] <=> a[1]}
```

Comment: You can instantiate a hash using `myhash=Hash.new(0)` so you don't need to check whether a value with a given key already exists, just increment it.